# Python: Delete Objects and Free Up Space

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, reference, destructor

Python documentation said that an object is considered deleted if the reference counts to the object is zero and the difference between **del** and **__del__** is that:

- **del** reduces the reference count to an object by one
- **__del__** executes when the reference count to an object is zero

That means if we keep delete the reference to an object until the reference count to zero. It would executes **__del__** to delete the object to free up memory.

However, what is troubling me is that:

- If I create an object and bind the object to the name **ObjectX**. It
  would increase the reference count by 1, right?
- If I create a list with the name **ListY** and I append the **ListY**
  with **ObjectX**. It means that it would increase the reference count
  to 2, right?
- Now, if I delete **ObjectX** and **ListY**, would the reference count
  to the object is still remains as 1 and the object is still remaining
  sitting there in hard disk waiting for some kind soul to come and kill it?

Any comments and thoughts are welcomed....

By the way, if what is happening is really what I understand about deleting object in Python. Is there any good suggestion for how to delete an object that is appended into a list and free up the memory space?

```
class Slave:

def __init__(self):
    self.name=""

def __del__(self):
    print("SLAVE DEAD")

def sequence():

   SlaveX=Slave()
   slaveList=list()
   slaveList.append(SlaveX)

del SlaveX
   print("I AM NOT DEAD YET")
   del slaveList
```

Comment: It won't be on your hard disk - when you close python it goes away.

Comment: If you deleted both references, why would the reference count still be 1?

Comment: When you delete ObjectX it does down by one., When you delete ListY it goes down by another one.

Comment: Because the amount of data that I have to handle is quite huge. I afraid memory leak would occur before the program finish running.

Comment: @doctorlove.. Is it? Because I did code something inside __del__ and it would print something out on terminal if __del__ is executed. But I didn't get any output on terminal after I delete ObjectX and ListY

Comment: Ah - ok - can you add your class definition too so we have something to reproduce?

Comment: You never call `__del__`, that's called for you when the count goes to zero.  You can call `del` if you like, but just exiting the method where ObjectX and ListY are assigned will be enough to decrement the reference count to zero, so (usually) you don't need to call `del`.

Comment: @doctorlove.. You were right. I may be confused about it when I was experimenting with it.

Comment: your indenting of `del SlaveX` doesn't look correct!  and slaveList will go out of scope when you exit the method anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagine a simple class:

```
class Thingy:
    pass
```

Now I can create an object of this class and call it `george`:

```
george = Thingy()
```

Now I have created an instance of the class and I have one reference to it.  Somewhere this count is maintained and set to 1.

I can make a new variable called `mary` and assign it to the same object:

```
mary = george
```

Now I still only have one object, but I have two references to it.  If I call methods on `george`, this affects the object referred to by `mary` because it's the same instance.

As you mention lists, let's add it to a list as well, but essentially it's exactly the same, it increases the reference count to 3.

```
my_objects = []
my_objects.append(george)
```

Now there are three references.  Now, still inside this method, let's remove the references again

```
george = None    # reference count drops to 2
mary = 3         # reference count drops to 1
my_objects.pop() # reference count drops to 0
```

when the count drops to 0, the python runtime realises this (maybe not straight away, but quickly enough) and calls the `__del__` method on the instance.  You don't care about this, you just let the references disappear.

> Now, if I delete ObjectX and ListY, would the reference count to the object still remain as 1?

No, it would drop to zero.

> and the object is still remaining sitting there in hard disk waiting for some kind soul to come and kill it?

No, it was only held in memory, and will be deleted and the memory freed again.

Comment: I have idea about how the destructor works now. Thanks for the explanation.